# What's the best gem/plugin to develop a Facebook Canvas/iFrame App (Rails 2.3.8, Ruby 1.8.7)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, cucumber, facebooker

we're developing a Facebook Canvas App in Rails 2.3.8, we tried a couple of gems out there and for now we're using [mini_fb](https://github.com/appoxy/mini_fb) but it's not really well documented and we're having some issue with the authentication/authorization process, and more importantly we couldn't find a tutorial on how integrate cucumber.

I know there're plenty of options out there: [facebooker](https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker) (too old?), [oauth2 gem](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2), [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth), [mogli](https://github.com/mmangino/mogli) and so on.

What we ideally need is:

- Support for Canvas/iFrame app (not just Facebook connect)
- Support for the new OAuth 2.0 for Canvas (beta) [facebook docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas) & for the old REST API as well
- Documentation (very hard to find, also cause Facebook API are in first place not so extensively documentend, especially for Ruby)
- Support/Documentation/Tutorials for Cucumber integration
- Cover basic API features like Wall posting, Friends handling ...

**What's the best option in your opinion/past experience?**

Thank you guys,

Leo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Koala...

https://github.com/arsduo/koala/

Very well documented and maintained.

Works with Ruby 1.8/1.9 & Rails 2/3